# Capitalize JQuery Mobile Dropdown Value

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I have a JQuery Mobile page with the following [`select`](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/forms/selects/) tag:

```
<select id="menu">
    ...
</select>
```

I tried to capitalize the text:

```
#menu{
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

But it only capitalize the value/text in `option`. I want also to capitalize the value that is selected.

Comment: Have you an example somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to apply the style to the jqm button which shows the selected option

```
.ui-select .ui-btn-text {
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
```